# avtovacuum freeze with create index CONCURRENTLY produces blocking

Tags: postgresql

We have a large table frequently updated and 95% of time we have running vacuum freeze:
"autovacuum: VACUUM public.x (to prevent wraparound)" process description.

When run create index CONCURRENTLY during the period of the autovacuum freeze, I got series of blocking:
avtovacuum (ShareUpdateExclusiveLock) blocks create index CONCURRENTLY (ShareLock)
at the same time create index CONCURRENTLY (ShareLock) blocks UPDATES (RowExclusiveLock)

From the official documentation:
*Autovacuum workers generally don't block other commands. If a process attempts to acquire a lock that conflicts with the SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock held by autovacuum, lock acquisition will interrupt the autovacuum. For conflicting lock modes, see Table 13.2. **However, if the autovacuum is running to prevent transaction ID wraparound (i.e., the autovacuum query name in the pg_stat_activity view ends with (to prevent wraparound)), the autovacuum is not automatically interrupted.***

Currently we are not able to create indexes due to the blocking issue. And cannot tune the autovacuum freeze to run less often due to high resource usage and spikes, so we decreased autovacuum_freeze_max_age to 90 000 000.

How to overcome the problem of blocking conflict between autovacuum and create index?

Thanks

P.S.
PostgreSQL 15.3 on RDS.

I tried to reproduce the issue with pgbench and see the same blocking problem.

Comment: If you have lots of transactions and you reduce `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` then that means autovacuum will have to run all the time. Which seems to be what you are complaining about. This doesn't make any sense to me. Is there a typo in your question?

Comment: Is this one time like "it has been running for a long time and got close to have TID wraparound" or is this a routine for your database that lives at the edge :) ? I mean there are ~2 billion TIDs and if this is a general problem(if the application uses that much transactions and you always see TID wraparound warnings on the logs) there might be something else to think about it. Just out of curiosity what is the size of the table?

Comment: From the manual about autovacuum_freeze_max_age: `the default is a relatively low 200 million transactions`. You have now set it to a mere 90 million, so it runs more often. To me it looks like you moved into the wrong direction and you should have increased that number. For example 500 million or so.

Comment: There seems to be some mistake here.  CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY does not take ShareLock, and does not block UPDATE.  Maybe there is some extra unstated edge in your lock graph.

Comment: The table size is 4.5TB and we have about 150 millions inserts per day.

Comment: The autovacuum process executes all the operations supported by the general VACUUM
command, such as reclaiming dead rows, freezing the transaction ID, and refreshing table
statistics. autovacuum processes tables in one of the two following modes:
● Normal mode: A non-blocking operation that never blocks user operations on the table
autovacuum terminates the execution of normal operation whenever it blocks a
user-initiated operation
● Aggressive mode or uninterruptible anti-wraparound mode: A blocking operation that runs to completion by blocking data definition language (DDL) operations.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/static/solutions/optimizing-monitoring-troubleshooting-vacuum-operations-postgresql.pdf

Comment: And, yes, so? Have you tried(on the production you should not try, but sometimes there is nothing else to do)/implemented what @Frank Heikens said?